# Torsion ideal in symmetric algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $D$ be a commutative domain, $M$ a $D$-module without torsion, and $S(M)$ its symmetric algebra.

> Is the $D$-torsion ideal of $S(M)$ the prime ideal of $S(M)$?

Comment: What do you mean by the D-torsion ideal?

Comment: Ideal of elements of S(M) which are annihilated by some nonzero element of D

Comment: Yes, that is true.  I refuse to refer to a ring by $D$, since that is too often used for both (a) division algebras, and (b) rings of differential operators.  Let $R$ be a commutative ring that is an integral domain.  Let $U$ be the multiplicative system of all nonzero elements of $R$.  Let $R\to F$ be the localization of $R$ at $U$, i.e., the fraction field.  Then for any $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, $(M\otimes_R N)\otimes_R F$ is canonically isomorphic to $(M\otimes_R F)\otimes_F (N\otimes_R F)$.  Thus the natural map $U^{-1} S_R^\bullet(M)\to S_F^\bullet(M\otimes_R F)$ is an isomorphism . . .

Comment: The image of $S_R^\bullet(M)$ in $U^{-1}S_R^\bullet(M)$ is precisely the quotient of $S_R^\bullet(M)$ by the ideal you mention.  Finally, since $M\otimes_R F$ is a vector space over the field $F$, the symmetric algebra $S_F^\bullet(M\otimes_R F)$ is an integral domain.

Comment: As I understand, the symmetric algebra of a vector space V over a field F is the ring of polynomials with indeterminates set bijective  to the basis of V  ?

Comment: @AlgirdasRugys: Yes, the symmetric algebra of a vector space $V$ with a specified basis $B$ over a field $F$ is isomorphic to a ring of polynomials with coefficients in $F$ and indeterminate set $B$.  This is an integral domain.

Comment: Let R be any commutative ring and  M be any R-module containing  a prime submodule P  of M.  So, in the symmetric algebra S(M) the exists the unique  prime ideal which intersects with M by P and is minimal with respect to this property.

Comment: @AlgirdasRugys: "So in the symmetric algebra $S(M)$ the exists the unique prime ideal ..."  I do not understand how this relates to the previous discussion.

Comment: Lets look to the proper submodules of a module M which are intersections of prime ideals of S(M) with M. Previous discussion showes that these intersections are exactly so called prime submodules of M. More over, the unique minimal prime of S(M) lying over given prime in M has a clear description –  Algirdas Rugys 52 mins ago